# Swift Concurrency - How to get a Result from a task not working

Tags: swift, concurrency, task

I tried to put this example into a simple project + ViewController but can't get it to compile
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-get-a-result-from-a-task

I'm trying to call `fetchQuotes()` from an IBAction via a button tap, however because `fetchQuotes` is marked `async`, I'm getting an error.

I know that I can wrap the call to `fetchQuotes()` in a task:

```
Task { 
  fetchQuotes() 
}
```

, but this doesn't make sense to me since `fetchQuotes` is already creating tasks.

Can anyone advise?

Here is my code:

```
// https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-get-a-result-from-a-task

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    @IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: Any) {
       fetchQuotes()
    }

    func fetchQuotes() async {
        let downloadTask = Task { () -> String in
            let url = URL(string: "https://hws.dev/quotes.txt")!
            let data: Data

            do {
                (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            } catch {
                throw LoadError.fetchFailed
            }

            if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                return string
            } else {
                throw LoadError.decodeFailed
            }
        }

        let result = await downloadTask.result

        do {
            let string = try result.get()
            print(string)
        } catch LoadError.fetchFailed {
            print("Unable to fetch the quotes.")
        } catch LoadError.decodeFailed {
            print("Unable to convert quotes to text.")
        } catch {
            print("Unknown error.")
        }
    }
}

enum LoadError: Error {
    case fetchFailed, decodeFailed
}
```

Here's a screenshot of my code + Xcode error:
[image]

Comment: Post your code and error message as text and not an image please.

Comment: have the result set a class variable

Comment: I've added code as text (I wanted the compiler error to show sorry!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this doesn't make sense to me since fetchQuotes is already creating tasks

What `fetchQuotes` is internally doing is an implementation detail, it might as well not explicitly create any tasks, or not even be doing async calls.

Now, the `async` part of the method declaration tells the compiler the method might suspend the caller thread, thus any caller needs to provide an async context when calling the method. Note that I said *might suspend* not *will suspend*, this is a subtle, but important difference.

The tasks created by the method are valid only during the method execution, so if you need to be able to call the method from a non-async context you'll have to create new tasks.

However, you can tidy-up your code by providing a non-async overload:

```swift
func fetchQuotes() {
    Task {
        await fetchQuotes()
    }
}
```

, which can be called from your `@IBAction`

```swift
@IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: Any) {
    fetchQuotes()
}
```

There's no escaping out of this, if you want to be able to call an async function from a non-async context, then you'll need a `Task`, regardless on how the called method is implemented. Structured concurrency tasks are not reusable.

Answer (score 1):

> but this doesn't make sense to me since fetchQuotes is already creating tasks

Irrelevant; you've internalized a false rule, or failed to internalize the real rule. This has nothing to do with who is "creating tasks". It has to do with the real rule, the most fundamental rule of Swift's `async/await`, which is:

**You can only call an `async` method from within an `async` context.**

Well, the method `buttonTap` is not an `async` method, so your call to `fetchQuotes` is not being made within an `async` context. That's illegal, and the compiler stops you dead.

But if you wrap the call to `fetchQuotes` in a Task initializer, that *is* an `async` context. Success!

---

<sub>Basically, the effect you're seeing is what I call the *regress of doom*. Since every call to an `async` method must be in an `async` context, but since *your* events from Cocoa, such as an IBAction, are *not* `async`, how can *your* code *ever* call an `async` method? The answer is a Task initializer: it gives you a place to get started.</sub>

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  I said I already know that I can wrap fetchQuotes in a Task.  I'm asking how I can call fetchQuotes which already creates a Task without creating another Task.  It's a code smell.  Thx